# Keycloak Error Invalid Redirect URI Mobile App

Tags: expo, keycloak

I have a mobile app that is setup with the following settings in `app.json`:

```
"expo": {
    ...
    "scheme": "myapp",
    ...
}
```

When I try to login within the app, I get the following error:

[image]

I looked into the docker logs and the deep-link is setup correctly. This is the error message:

```
2024-03-05T14:13:41.071050158Z 2024-03-05 14:13:41,063 WARN [org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-67) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=e42bff21-b759-4547-b223-95d2185b6c92, clientId=my-app, userId=null, ipAddress=xxx.xxx.xx.xx, error=invalid_redirect_uri, redirect_uri=myapp://
```

And this is my settings within the client inside keycloak:

**Valid redirect URIs:** `myapp://*`

What am I missing here? The scheme from the keycloak configuration matches the redirect uri within the logs.

Comment: From the error i could say the redirect_uri you pass to the keycloak for authentication is not same as configured in the keycloak

Comment: It is the same, I have provided all the details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to solve this problem, don't know the underlying issue though.

In Keycloak it is not possible to specify the redirect uri as `myapp://` as it complains that it is not a valid uri. That was the reason for which I specified it as `myapp://*`. My guess is that this is the issue and the wildcard is somehow not handled properly.

My solution was to specify the redirect uri as `myapp://redirect`. This is a valid uri in keycloak settings as well. Now it works.

Comment: You should accept your answer to let others know that the question is closed :-)